# Weil-Châtelet group

Tags: elliptic-curves

Sorry if this is obvious. I'd like to understand why the map

WC(E/Q) -> H^1(Gal(**Q**/Q), E(**Q**))

is bijective. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be in chapter 10 of Silverman's AEC (sorry if I'm wrong about this!).

Comment: See also Bjorn Poonen's course notes http://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf, section 4.5 on twists, which also cites Serre.